# unsupported major minor version error 51.0

Tags: java, r, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, sparkr

Hi i am trying to run the sparkR in the cluster.when i am running the sparkR using yarn client i am getting error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitDriverBootstrapper$.main(SparkSubmitDriverBootstrapper.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitDriverBootstrapper.main(SparkSubmitDriverBootstrapper.scala)
```

i tried the following query.

```
/SparkR-pkg/lib/SparkR/sparkR-submit --master yarn-client /home/user/examples/pi.R yarn-client 4
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your start-up command? You need to set SPARK_HOME, it's the path to your Spark directory when you run localy, on a cluster, you should probably point to your cluster.

Comment: ya i know how can i find the spark path in cluster.i am using amazon ec2

Comment: just type env in the command line and see the env variables.

Comment: check java version on your cluster, It seems it is <1.7